# "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED": "The document element did not contain the encoded document, 'documentId=<x>'possibly missing from Content-Disposition header."

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I have a concern regarding DocuSign, that i can't manage to resolve, Hope that someone could give me a hint or spot what I'm missing.

Currently in the application , a user can select a document to sign, so when i try to implement the signing part with DocuSign i got this error  "404 : "NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED": "The document element did not contain the encoded document, 'documentId='possibly missing from Content-Disposition header." ".

here a bunch of code that i'm working on it for the moment i have implemented two kind of solution, one is working and the other one not  :

Not working :
$args["doccontent"] is the way i call the document from database(its a pdf).

```
                                        
      
   $doc_internal_name = str_replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/","C:/laragon2/www/ApplicationNAme/public/",$args['doccontent']); 
    
    $doc_content = file_get_contents($doc_internal_name );
   
    $base64FileContent = base64_encode($doc_content);
 
    $document = new Document(
        [
            'document_base64' => $base64FileContent,
            'name' => 'testdoc',
            'file_extension' => "pdf",
            'document_id' => 1
        ]
    );
  
      
        /* Create the signer recipient model */
   

        $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
            'email' => email,  
            'name' => name , 
            'recipient_id' => '1', 
            'routing_order' => '1',
            'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
        ]);
  
        /* Create a signHere tab (field on the document) */
        $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 
            'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 
            'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
        ]);
  
        /* Create a signHere 2 tab (field on the document) */
        $signHere2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '/sn2/', 
            'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '40', 
            'anchor_x_offset' => '40'
        ]);
         
        $signer->settabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere, $signHere2]]));
 
        $envelopeDefinition  = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
            'documents' => [$document],
            'recipients' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
           
           
        ]);
       
       
        return $envelopeDefinition;
```

Working :  when i specify directly the same path of the same document in the solution that is not working :

```
 $content = file_get_contents("../public/uploads/zbD0nVz3NoEYjg2ttHnrhoJ7JM7OQbqSVQCnNT8U.pdf");
 $base64FileContent = base64_encode($content);
    $document = new Document(
        [
            'document_base64' => $base64FileContent,
            'name' => 'test',
            'file_extension' => 'pdf',
            'document_id' => 1
        ]
    );
     /* Create the signer recipient model */
   

        $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
            'email' => email,  
            'name' => name , 
            'recipient_id' => '1', 
            'routing_order' => '1',
            'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
        ]);
  
        /* Create a signHere tab (field on the document) */
        $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 
            'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 
            'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
        ]);
  
        /* Create a signHere 2 tab (field on the document) */
        $signHere2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '/sn2/', 
            'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '40', 
            'anchor_x_offset' => '40'
        ]);
         
        $signer->settabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere, $signHere2]]));
 
        $envelopeDefinition  = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
            'documents' => [$document],
            'recipients' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
           
           
        ]);
       
       
        return $envelopeDefinition;
```

but i want the first one to work, cause different users will use the application and they will be signing different document

thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you show us one example of this `$args["doccontent"]` ?

Comment: thank for your replay : when i dump  $doc_internal_name  here's what i got "../public/uploads/zbD0nVz3NoEYjg2ttHnrhoJ7JM7OQbqSVQCnNT8U.pdf"                  
 is that what you want to know ?

Comment: In this case try this : in your working code replace this `$content = file_get_contents("../public/uploads/xP7ZKqRBWPcb9aXMqzjP0l8zXt285xHOpYHGRZZf.pdf");` by this `$content = file_get_contents($args["doccontent"]);`

Comment: When i  do that i get : Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded.

Comment: I think it's another error related to the size of data that you have, but the first proposition will work

Comment: ok i will try to check on the size of the data, but it's the same doc for both method, that's what i don't understand, it's just the way i call it that it's different.                                                                        thank again for your help

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not directly related to the DocuSign APIs.
When you send bytes to the API - you have to make sure there are actual bytes of a file that you're sending. Your code has an issue getting these bytes - so the API is returning the correct error that no bytes were received for the document.

Make sure that the first version of the code has the correct URL for the PDF you want to read and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but what i don't understand is that the url is the same for both version, it's just that that in the second version a write it bold in the code and in the first version am using a value . the dump of  $doc_internal_name is "../public/uploads/zbD0nVz3NoEYjg2ttHnrhoJ7JM7OQbqSVQCnNT8U.pdf it's the same one that i use in the second version

Comment: can you please, give me a hint or what i should do to fix this issues. Thank you in advance

Comment: debug your code, see what is the value of $args["doccontent"]

Comment: see what is the value of $doc_internal_name and also most importantly the value of $base64FileContent

Comment: On debug mode : value of $args["doccontent"] : 127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/XSCabXEMXyg2ULin8Z2c39wIeLeTdyqI0kkLrlZM.pdf              
the value of $doc_internal_name : C:/laragon/www/ApplicationName/public/uploads/XSCabXEMXyg2ULin8Z2c39wIeLeTdyqI0kkLrlZM.pdf                                                                                                          
Value of $base64FileContent : "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRm...

Comment: ok, what about the rest of your code? is it the same in both cases? because you do have your working code somewhere

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand you can you please specify ?

Comment: for the version 1 of the code i can't sign but with the version 2 i can sign and be redirected to the application

Comment: Yes, but this is not the full code. Can you post version 1 and 2 the entire code you are writing to make the API call to sign

Comment: i've added the complete code of this function for both version in the main post. it's the same it's only the way i call the value of document that change. thank you so much for reply and patience

Comment: There's something that is not correct, I can't know what it is, but triple check everything. What you can also do is copy the few lines from version 2 to version 1, so that both of these run one after the other and see if it works

Comment: Another approach, is to hardcode the base64 value you wrote earlier in the code of version 1 and see if that works

Comment: basically start line by line debugging and starting with code that works, adding 1 line, see if it still works, adding another line until it breaks and see why

Comment: ok i will do that , i already hardcoded the value of base64 in version 1 and it's work, it's only working when the value is hardcoded, if not i got the error. thanks again

Comment: So, let me understand this
You have a variable X, the value if that variable is Y
If you put X - doesn't work
If you put Y - works?
That is logic contradiction, you need to quadruple check everything, this cannot be, it's a basic concept of computer science, if a variable value is Y, you can put Y or this variable and must get the same result

Comment: the variable X has value X1  i got it from database , when i tried to use it in version1 i got this error so i took the value X1 and hardcoded directly in my code that is version2 and it's work perfectly.

Comment: Then your issue is getting the value from the database, not sure how you do that

Comment: i will check the value coming from database. thankyou